# How to replace a substring only once?

Tags: regex, ios-shortcut

I have the following string:

```
Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,Midday Routines
```

I want to write a regular expression such that I will get exactly the following:

```
Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,⚡ Midday Routines
```

How to do it with some Regex that will only match the second occurrence of `Midday Routines` in this case?

I was replacing the `Midday Routines` with `⚡ Midday Routines`, but it seems iPhone Shortcuts by default replace **all** occurrences, and I got:

```
Log First Meal Time,Twitter,⚡ Midday Routines Done,⚡ Midday Routines
```

I am new to regular expression and I have no ideas...

Please help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the rationale for the substitution?

Comment: With only one example, it's hard to answer. Can you describe the substitution more generally? Otherwise I'd just say replace `Midday Routines Done,` with `Midday Routines Done,⚡`

Comment: What exactly do you want to replace a string? Is it the last string after the comma? It would help if you specify the position

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully it clarified the substitution now.

Comment: @Dillion Yes, I want to just replace the last string after the last comma.

Comment: Clarifying the question helped. I've provided a solution

Comment: Is there another possible input or you need something only for the given case? For example, is it possible to have more than two occurrences?

Comment: What language?  Not all regex engines are the same?

Comment: Right.  Regular expressions do not involve substitutions.  Regular expressions are sometimes used in library routines that DO substitution, but we need to know which language/library/routine.

Comment: @TimRoberts The ios-shortcut tag implies ICU compatiblity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IOS Shortcuts, you should be able to use [ICU Regex](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html).

For Match, use: `(Midday Routines)(.*?)\1`

For Replace, use: `$1$2⚡ $1`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not well defined. From you comment it looks like you want to insert a character after the last comma in the string.

You can do that with with lookarounds:

```
(?<=,)(?=[^,]+$)
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=,)` -- positive lookbehind for a comma
- `(?=[^,]+$)` -- positive lookahead for anything not a comma until end of string

You did not specify the language. In JavaScript you would do a replace:

```
'Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,Midday Routines'.replace(/(?<=,)(?=[^,]+$)/, '⚡ ')
// returns: 'Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,⚡ Midday Routines'
```

***Learn more about regex:*** https://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Codev/TWikiPresentation2018x10x14Regex

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a language.  Here is one way to do it in Java.

Use `String.replaceFirst`.

- `()` capture group
- `.*?` - reluctant quantifier
- `$n` back reference to the captured strings.
- First capture group is the first occurrence plus everything just before the second occurrence.
- Second capture group is the second occurrence.

```
String s = "Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,Midday Routines"; 
s = s.replaceFirst("(Midday Routines.*?)(Midday Routines)", "$1\u26A1 $2");
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
Log First Meal Time,Twitter,Midday Routines Done,⚡ Midday Routines
```

The above will work regardless of what comes after your initial string.

Answer (score -1):

From what I understand, you want to match the last string after the last comma.

Here's the regex:

```
(?<=,)[^,]*$
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=,)`: lookbehind that verifies that there's a comma before the string
- `[^,]*`: negated character class with quantifier that specifies - "match every other characters multiple times except a comma"
- `$`: anchor that specifies that this pattern should end the sentence

So this pattern ensures that a comma precedes the string, and there's no comma after the preceded comma, and this is at the end of the sentence. This way, you match only the last string that doesn't have any comma after it.

[Verify here](https://regex101.com/r/5E7dRX/1)